# How to export file with special character in it node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

How do I export file with special character in it?

For Example :

```
export { default as update-rfnsa-task } from './update-rfnsa-task';
```

Comment: Why do you need to export it with `-` (symbol). You can use camel case `updateRfnsaTask`.

Comment: Module exports need to follow the [rules for JavaScript identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier). `-` isn't allowed.

Comment: This is like asking: "How can I name a JavaScript variable using dashes" ‍♂️

Comment: @LionelRowe - Please write an answer.

Comment: @kennarddh other part of the code. I get key with special character in it. then I load this particular  exported file using the key which we received from other party

Comment: @PradeepPoojari if possible you can ask the **other party** to send in compatable format keys. If that's not possible you can create a keyMapper object where you get the relevant  module to be exported based on the key.

Answer (score 1):

Like all JavaScript variables, module exports need to follow the [rules for JavaScript identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier):

> In JavaScript, identifiers are case-sensitive and can contain Unicode letters, `$`, `_`, and digits (`0-9`), but may not start with a digit.

Some examples of valid identifiers:

```js
fooBar
$dollar_sign
var012
文字
```

Some examples of *invalid* identifiers:

```js
emoji
includes-hyphen
012startsWithNumber
```

In other words, an identifier containing `-` is not valid in JavaScript.